# Creating a table with bracket and a equal sign with in it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on Visual Studios 2012 and I was wondering if anyone can give a step-by-step how to get a equal sign within the Bracket, as shown on the images below.

**Report**

[image: Report]

**Row Groups**

[image: Row Groups]

Comment: Surely you realize how vague this question is....where did you get those screen shots?  Are they from somewhere in the visual studio IDE UI?  If so, care to explain where?  Are they from an application you've seen before or are trying to mimic?  If so, which one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.